# Can we pass datatable from Business layer to presentation Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project to make a 3-tier architecture, i need to ask if we can pass a data table directly to presentation layer as it comes from data layer,is it a good practice ?

Comment: You could, but why?  The business layer should take the (more or less) raw data from the data layer and apply the required business logic to it, and pass that transformed data to the presentation layer (IMO).  Otherwise the business layer is nothing but a pass-through and you 3-tier just became 2.

Comment: Have you research something on the topic ?

Comment: What is the database tier implemented with ADO.NET or Entity Framework or else ?

Comment: If you want to pass DataTable directly to Presentation layer, it means you are Bypassing the busssiness logic layer, in short you are violating the 3 tier architecture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **IMHO your question is very debatable**

Consider below points to take decision in such case:

1. If database provider is your custom implemented using ADO.NET or Entity Framework  or any other ORM then change to POCO classes and pass those POCO instances don't use DataTable.
2. Use DataTable if your results are not fixed such that you can create POCO classes.

Check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET) an old article on using DataTable in Three-tier architechture.

Read online benefits of using POCO and DataTable for more.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can but it is not at all a good practice. Better you have a Entity class for each of the data table in DB. Each class has Public Properties similar to your DB columns. All these things should reside under your Business Layer. In Data Access Layer get the data from DB in the format of data table, pass to Business Layer and convert this table to Collection of Entity object and pass to your Presentation Layer.

Answer (score 0):

In Cs Page .........

```
public DataTable dtDistinctFRU;
dtDistinctFRU= dsData.Tables[0];
```

In aspx Page........

```
 <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dtDistinctFRU.Rows)
     {
 %>
....some html ...

<% Response.Write(rowNum); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never do this, because why would you need these different layers in the first place if you pass identical objects through them? Anyway, as this is an architectural question there is no right answer for this, only opinions.

My opinion: I like operations to be business operations, clearly showing intend about what you might expect from them, instead of CRUD operations. You only pass what is needed for the business operation to complete, and in the case of queries, you only get back what you really need for your UI. This means that you design specific data contracts instead of generic data tables. This means that the data layer works with the data entities and maps these to your domain entities (for example, using EF code first). Then these domain entities are mapped to the data transfer objects of your service; which you use in your UI.

You could read the series at http://tinyurl.com/d99w8rl to get some inspiration (especially part 2).